# UILocalNotification in Birthday App iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, uilocalnotification, reminders

In birthday app which is the best place to check birthdates and set its UILocalNotification in iOS.

Iss didfinishlaunching the best place? or any other.

Answer (score 1):

That is a good place to schedule the notification if you need to check it only once.

If data changes often I suggest you put it in `applicationDidBecomeActive:` since iOS might not remove the app from memory each time.

You also need to make sure that you schedule only one notification, and not each time the application is started.

Comment: What if I add contact with today's birthday and I don't open my birthday app. I guess no notification would set and hence no use of UILocalNotification :|

Comment: In that case you would need your application to work in background mode and check periodically for changes.

Comment: So for every now and then I need to open my birthday app and sync its contacts. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, or you might use background tasks for that I think. I am not sure though. Check this out: http://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/backgrounding-for-ios

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
  NSLog(@"Notification fired"!);
}
```

if your in foregroud it will call this method. then you can use this method also.